# How to get raspberry's stats in python code

Tags: python, statistics, package

I would like to retrieve the stats (Ram, storage, ...) of my raspberry pi in a python code but I can't find how. An idea ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) library to assist you with this.

Have a look at the below code snippet which I copied verbatim from this [page](https://amalgjose.com/2020/04/27/simple-python-program-to-get-the-system-status-of-a-raspberry-pi/):

```
import psutil

# Get cpu statistics
cpu = str(psutil.cpu_percent()) + '%'

# Calculate memory information
memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
# Convert Bytes to MB (Bytes -> KB -> MB)
available = round(memory.available/1024.0/1024.0,1)
total = round(memory.total/1024.0/1024.0,1)
mem_info = str(available) + 'MB free / ' + str(total) + 'MB total ( ' + str(memory.percent) + '% )'

# Calculate disk information
disk = psutil.disk_usage('/')
# Convert Bytes to GB (Bytes -> KB -> MB -> GB)
free = round(disk.free/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0,1)
total = round(disk.total/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0,1)
disk_info = str(free) + 'GB free / ' + str(total) + 'GB total ( ' + str(disk.percent) + '% )'

print("CPU Info–> ", cpu)
print("Memory Info–>", mem_info)
print("Disk Info–>", disk_info)
```